# IBAction Events meaning

Tags: ios, swift, documentation, ibaction

I've been trying to get my head around Swift and building a simple iOS app.
I've checked online, but I'm not entirely sure what to search anyway, I was just wondering does anyone know a website or can just straight up tell me what all of the IBAction Events mean.

Touch Up Inside means when the button is clicked and released, although I'm not sure why.
There is touch up outside, Editing changed, editing did begin, and another 10 or so.

I would really appreciate it.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are defined in the `UIControl` class documentation under constants:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Control_Events

A touch down event is when the finger touches the screen. A touch up event is when the finger releases the screen. If you tap the screen, there will be a touch down then a touch up.

Answer (score 0):

The IBAction means IB is Interface Builder

The Action means the button will trigger some event.

And Touch Up Inside,

Touch Up Outside define the condition

which will trigger the button to do some event.